# Не удаётся открыть проект после использования Xcode 11 beta

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

По чистой случайности, забыв в каком Xcode работаю открыл свой релизный  проект. Xcode beta после удачной перезаписи теперь не даёт открыть проект в стабильной версии выдавай ошибку

The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 11.0.
This version does not support iOS 13.0 system colors. Open this document with at least Xcode 11.0.

Есть ли возможность как-то пофиксить данную оплошность без восстановления проекта с бекапа 7ми дневной давности ?

Я уже пробовал заменять шапку в storyboard в просмотре через as source. Не помогло, проект просто крашится при попытке его запустить

Сталкивались ли вы с похожей проблемой, и как удалось ее решить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 11.0. This version does not support iOS 13.0 system colors. Open this document with at least Xcode 11.0.

Вам необходимо открыть этот storyboard в Xcode 11 и заменить все системные цвета, так как новые цвета доступны только в новых версиях и не являются чистыми.

Либо открыть storyboard как source code и первым делом удалить строчки:

```
<capability name="iOS 13.0 system colors" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
и все где есть 
cocoaTouchSystemColor
```

А затем в Interface builder восстановить нужные цвета.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую это сделать. Лишь бы Xcode не крашнул снова. Он очень не стабильный

Comment: Вау! это реально сработало
Спасибо тебе большое.

У меня в проекте было еще 3 строчки с cocoaTouchSystemColor
после их удаления проект запустился в стабильной версии

надеюсь при модерации моей апп эпл не завернут ее найдя строки с xcode11